# Display all relevant names in group header

Tags: crystal-reports

My subreport takes data like this:

```
1. PersonA, ValueA, ValueB, Group1
2. PersonA, ValueE, ValueF, Group1
3. PersonB, ValueA, ValueB, Group1
4. PersonB, ValueE, ValueF, Group1
5. PersonC, ValueC, ValueD, Group2
6. PersonC, ValueG, ValueH, Group2
```

Every `Person` with the same `Group` number will have the same `Value` entries. There could be any number per `Group`, but they will always match up perfectly. So I want to display the data like this:

```
PersonA  
PersonB

-------ValueA ValueB
-------ValueE ValueF

PersonC

-------ValueC ValueD   
-------ValueG ValueH
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this structure. Where would a hypothetical `ValueJ` go if it was part of `PersonB`, but *not* part of `PersonA`?

Comment: Everyone with the same group number has the same value entries.  It could be 1 or more, but they will always be the same for the a given group

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now - So technically, you're only grouping by `Group#` and you just want to display all the involved `Person` names in the group header?

Comment: Yes I think so. That and only show the values corresponding to that group only once for all the people.

Comment: Great - Is there any chance of you moving this outside of a subreport? Or perhaps is there a fixed number of Groups that won't ever change? There's technically a way to do this without either of those, but you won't like the work involved.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be contained to the subreport.  I tried to see if I could move it to the main report, but that wasn't an option.  The groups are dynamic for that particular report.  Basically it is a hash that is generated in the database that can be used to group records together, but it will not be something that I can positively look for.  I am not afraid of work if I can get this to look like the business wants.  (Thanks a ton for looking into this)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you *could* do this in native Crystal by setting up a weird system of arrays and shared variables, but the best way to do this is with SQL.

In the subreport's *Database Expert*, go to *Add Command* and write a custom SQL statement that, for each group, concatenates all the `Person` names into a single String, separated by space characters. Then drop the resulting field into your `Group` Header.

I don't know your table structure or linkage, so you're probably on your own with writing the Query itself. If you run into trouble, you can submit a different [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) question to get past roadblocks.

Comment: Ok so i was able to write a sql query that returns "PersonA, PersonB" (basically all persons in a group as single string).  I am having trouble getting it formatted correctly in the Group Header.  There could be a few Persons (typically around 5), so how can I make it so that each is on a newline and the box grows downward?

Comment: @TheFityP Separate each of them with a Newline character. To get it to work across SQL and Crystal, I think you'll want `CHAR(13)` which basically acts like an `Enter` press